prove that the matrix multiplication yields sufficiently small entries
Let's define the following matrices:
\begin{align}
\Sigma_t= \sum_{k=0}^{t-1} x_k x_k^T \in \mathbb R^{n \times n},
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\tilde\Sigma_t= \sum_{k=0}^{t-1} w_k x_k^T \in \mathbb R^{n \times n},
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
0 \le w_k \leq \alpha x_k,\; k=0,\ldots,t,
\end{align}
and $0<\alpha<1$ also $x_k> 0$.
The inequalities here are element-wise. The vector $x_k \in \mathbb R^n$ is assumed to be positive entry-wise for $k=0,\,\ldots,\,t-1$. Let's define the matrix multiplication
\begin{align}
C=\tilde\Sigma_t \Sigma_t^{-1},
\end{align}
under the condition that $ \Sigma_t$ is invertible. The invertibility condition could be fulfilled as long as $t$ is large enough and that my vectors $x_k$ are rich enough, say for instance when they are randomly generated positive vectors.
I want to show that I could make the entries of $C$ as small as I please by picking a small enough $\alpha$. Note that the entries could still be negative, so my claim is essentially on the absolute value of the entries. This could have been straightforward if $\Sigma_t^{-1}\ge 0$ but I am not assuming this here. I would appreciate any help or references where to look for related results in the literature. Thanks in advance.
P.S. In the case $\Sigma_t^{-1}\ge 0$ we have that
\begin{align}
\tilde\Sigma_t \Sigma_t^{-1}\leq \alpha \Sigma_t \Sigma_t^{-1} \leq \alpha I
\end{align}
and the result follows immediately. However, when the matrix $\Sigma_t^{-1}$ contains negative elements the above reasoning fails.

why do you write $\begin{align}
0 \le w_k \leq \alpha x_k,; k=0,\ldots,t,
\end{align}$ and say $x_k\geq 0$ but then say $x_k$ is positive entry-wise?  This muddies the waters.  Just writing  $0 \le w_k \lt x_k$ is more concise and clear.  You also index $k$ from 0 to $t-1$ and $0$ to $t$ which doesn't make sense.  As an aside, since $\Sigma_t$ is a positive matrix, you should be able to prove that it is impossible for $\Sigma_t^{-1}$ to be a non-negative matrix.

Your comments have been incorporated. Thanks. And positive definiteness is irrelevant here. I have stated that the inequalities are entry-wise, i.e. $A>0$ means all the entries of $A$ are positive.

I never said anything about positive definiteness.  A positive matrix means all entries positive in this context e.g. read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem  .  Again you should prove to yourself that it is impossible for $\Sigma_t^{-1}$ to be a non-negative matrix.  [Another clue to what I meant is that $\Sigma_t$ positive definite which implies  $\Sigma_t^{-1}$ is positive definite so it is automatically non-negative definite, indicating that I meant something other than your interpretation.]

Yes, sure you did not mention anything about positive definiteness. Yes, I see. Via this we are excluding the possibility of having a positive inverse. I added the comment about the non-positivity of the inverse to point out the challenge in proving my statement. But again thanks for pointing out the flaws in my question, however sadly this leads me no where to finding an answer.

Yes, but the inverse being non-positive does not necessarily mean the statement is wrong, my claim is about the entries being small regardless if they are negative or positive.

If $\alpha$ can depend on $t$, $n$, and $x_k$, you can simply write out the entries of $\tilde{\Sigma}_t \Sigma_t^{-1}$ and estimate each entry by $C(t,n,x_k) \alpha$ without needing to calculate $\Sigma_t^{-1}$ explicitly.

@Hetebrij  $\alpha$ is in fact constant in my problem and is sufficiently small (in the orders of ~$10^{-2}$), but $w_k$ is generated randomly while adhering to the above linear constraint. I numerically verified my statement and it seems to always hold, but I am unable to prove it. What do you mean write out the entries of the matrix multiplication? doesn't that require writing an explicit formula for the inverse?
